# Can't catch the value entered via form in another .jsp file. Why?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have a form in index.jsp file, which allows to log into my app. I need to catch the inserted login  to use it in another file called mainPage.jsp using Java code. When I do:

```
String login = request.getParameter("login");
```

this string has null value. How can I catch the inserted value?

Here is my code from index.jsp with forms resaponsible for logging into my app:

```
<body>
<form id="log" method="post" onsubmit="return check()" action="mainPage.jsp">
        <div align="center">
            
            Login: <input type="text" id="login" name="login"/>
            <br/></br>
            
            Password: <input type="password" id="password"/>   
            <br/></br>
            
            <button name="login" type="submit">Log in!</button>
        </div> 
    </form> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function check() {
            var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var flag = false;
            
            var _users = JSON.parse(users);
            
            for (var i = 0; i < _users.length; i++) {
                if (_users[i].login == login && _users[i].password == password) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            
            if (flag == false) {   
                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "Wrong login or password!";
            }
            
            return flag;
        }        
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in your check method? If you want to check login and password you have to do it on server side. In your code it seems like you load all users to client size  and check it. In this case you just give all unencrypted data to user and anybody can find any password.
About main point in your question - why get parameter not work. In short - this method is for get query (like google.com/search?q=abc and getParameter("q") returns abc. You send POST method - it means that your params are in request.getBody(). You can parse it simplier with some library like spring

Comment: Ok, but how can I do it without Spring? Could you help me do this, @DmitryNazarenko?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what supposed to be the problem, was misusing the architecture of the .jsp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is in using wrong method:
HttpRequest.getParameter. This method finds parameter in URL. For example in this url

```
https://google.com/search?q=java
```

request.getParameter("q") returns java.

In your example you used POST query. It means that parameters will be in your request body in www-form-urlencoded format. Request will look like

```
login=login&password=password
```

The second problem is in using ids instead of names. To transfer params in  tag you need to use names, not ids. Also button with name parameter will send empty input. After pressing button you will see next result on server

```
login=login&login=
```

And it's what we not expected. In example below I used names to send params correctly. If you need css style - use classes or id parameters instead of html tag name

To parse it without external libraries we have to

1. Parse request body
2. Extract parameters
3. Send response to client

Simple example of this:

login.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
    <style>
        /* TODO: use classes of method to make styles */
        label, input {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label>Login: 
            <input type="text" name="login" />
        </label>
        <label>Password:
            <input label="password" type="password" name="password"/>
        </label>

        <button type="submit">Log in!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```java
@WebServlet(name = "login", value = "/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static final String IS_AUTHENTICATED_PARAM = "isAuthenticated";

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").include(request, response);
    }


    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Parse body
        String requestBody = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        //System.out.println(requestBody); - uncomment to view what is in body
        String login = getParamFromBodyUrlEncoded(requestBody, "login");
        String password = getParamFromBodyUrlEncoded(requestBody, "password");
        //In future you can setup secret cookie and check it in other pages
        if(login == null || password == null) {
            request.setAttribute(IS_AUTHENTICATED_PARAM, false);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("isAuthenticated", isCredentialsCorrect(login, password));
        }
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/loginResult.jsp").include(request, response);
    }

    private String getParamFromBodyUrlEncoded(String requestBody, String paramName) {
        String paramUrlEncoded = paramName + "=";//param format is like login=. We expect paramname like login
        //Search for param
        int paramWithNameStart = requestBody.indexOf(paramUrlEncoded);
        if(paramWithNameStart == -1) {
            return null;
        }
        //Set pointer after param name
        int paramStart = paramWithNameStart + paramUrlEncoded.length();
        //Param should end with & or end of string
        int paramEnd = requestBody.indexOf("&", paramStart);
        if(paramEnd == -1) {
            paramEnd = requestBody.length();
        }

        return requestBody.substring(paramStart, paramEnd);
    }

    private boolean isCredentialsCorrect(String login, String password) {
        if("admin".equals(login) && "password".equals(password)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

loginResult.jsp

```
<%@ page import="com.example.demo_jsp.LoginServlet" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login result</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1><%=(boolean)request.getAttribute(LoginServlet.IS_AUTHENTICATED_PARAM) ? 
        "Success authentication" : "Wrong login or password"%></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Dmitry Nazarenko for your comprehensive answer :-) However, I managed to do this much simpler and I post it as an answer to my question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally managed to do this in a quite simple way.
When I log in, I store login name in session and then extract it later in my program.

I do this by calling this part of code after logging into my app:

```
   if (request.getParameter("login") != null) {    
        session.setAttribute("_login", request.getParameter("login"));
   }
```

And then, I catch the name of the logged person by:

```
   String login = session.getAttribute("_login").toString();
```

It works pretty well! :-D

Comment: but the question was about other subject - you got request.getParameter("smth") - null value. If you get parameter from this request, you have changed your form method to get, and that is not right to transfer password throw get method - it's not common practice. So, my answer solved this problem, and you found not the best way to solve your problem

Comment: Lol I didn't change the form method to get

Comment: I think that simplier way to use small library with parsing features. You can look into http://sparkjava.com/ for example - it's very simple. Java servlet api is low level and in java projects usually works with frameworks

Comment: I get it, you store login name in session! It solves problem, but  it is not common way to solve this, and another programmer would be surprised as well as me. Anyway the question was about why I getting null, and simple way to solve the problem it's not an answer to your question. Also - I inderstand that you want to solve your problem in your way to learn, but usually developers use some kind of standart authentication method, like basic, jwt or token auth etc.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help and useful advices :-)